# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery, exists

I'm trying to create a stored procedure and I wrote this code using SQL Server, but I get the error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

and I don't know how to solve it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Calculus
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        -- **** Media (Average) **** --
        (SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(CC AS NUMERIC)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         FROM CHALLENGE AS Media),
        -- **** Mediana **** --
        (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(CC) % 2 = 0 
                THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ((SELECT TOP 1 CC 
                                     FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT CC FROM CHALLENGE ORDER  BY CC ASC) AS X
                                     ORDER  BY CC DESC)
                                  + (SELECT TOP 1 CC
                                     FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT CC FROM CHALLENGE ORDER  BY CC DESC) AS Y
                                     ORDER  BY CC ASC)) / 2)
                ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 CC
                      FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT CC FROM CHALLENGE ORDER  BY CC) AS X
                      ORDER  BY CC DESC)
                END AS Mediana
         FROM   CHALLENGE),
        -- **** Moda **** --
        (SELECT TOP 1 CC, COUNT(CC) AS Veces
         FROM CHALLENGE
         GROUP BY CC
         ORDER BY COUNT(CC)) AS Moda,
        -- **** Min **** --
        MIN(CC) AS Minimo,
        -- **** Max **** --
        MAX(CC) AS Maximo
    FROM
        CHALLENGE
END
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would say this isn't "fixable". There is pretty much nothing in there that is salvageable. It needs to be restarted. I count at least 9-10 select statements ALL of them hitting the exact same table. There are multiple logical and syntactical errors. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: But if you don't want to make this better and just make it work look at your Moda subquery, there are two columns in that. The fact that you can't find it is a pretty good sign it needs some major help.

Comment: @JuanPenaranda . . . What part of the error message don't you understand?  It seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by refactoring your stored procedure for the sake of clarity.

Sample for reference below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Calculus
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @Media varchar(max)
      DECLARE @Mediana varchar(max)
      DECLARE @topbottom numeric
      DECLARE @bottomtop numeric
      DECLARE @Moda varchar(max)
      SELECT 
            @Media= Cast(Avg(Cast (CC AS numeric)) AS varchar(max))
      FROM CHALLENGE

      SELECT 
        TOP 50 PERCENT CC 
      INTO #TOP
      FROM   CHALLENGE
      ORDER  BY CC ASC

      SELECT 
        TOP 50 PERCENT CC 
      INTO #BOTTOM
      FROM   CHALLENGE
      ORDER  BY CC DESC

      SELECT 
            TOP 1 @topbottom=CAST(CC as numeric)
      FROM   #TOP X
      ORDER  BY CC DESC 

      SELECT 
        TOP 1 @bottomtop=CAST(CC as numeric)
       FROM   #BOTTOM Y
       ORDER  BY CC ASC

      SELECT @Mediana=
            CASE
                WHEN Count(CC) % 2 = 0 THEN (@bottomtop+@topbottom)/2
                ELSE @topbottom
              END 
       FROM   CHALLENGE

      SELECT TOP 1 
        @Moda= CC
        FROM
      (
      SELECT CC,Count(CC) AS Veces
       FROM   CHALLENGE
       GROUP  BY CC
       )
       ORDER  BY Veces


      SELECT
        Media=@Media,
        Mediana=@Mediana,
        Moda= @Moda,
        Minimo=Min(CC),
        Maximo=Max(CC)
      FROM   CHALLENGE

      drop table #top
      drop table #bottom
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of the query is causing error.

It's a subquery and you are trying to return 2 columns out of it (which causes the error).

`TOP 1 CC` and `COUNT(CC)`

```
(SELECT TOP 1 CC
       ,COUNT(CC) AS Veces
 FROM CHALLENGE
 GROUP BY CC
 ORDER BY COUNT(CC)) AS Moda
```

Not sure what to suggest because for sure you are the only one who knows what you intended to get from here.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your query and put every sub querys in (OUTER APPLY)  join

like this :

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE Calculus
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT
              MediaTableName.MediaFieldName

        FROM
            CHALLENGE
        OUTER APPLY 
            (SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(CC AS NUMERIC)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as MediaFieldName
             FROM CHALLENGE AS t1
             WHERE t1.IDentity = CHALLENGE.IDentity /* this line create join condition and its up to you how use it*/
             ) as MediaTableName

    END
```

for each sub query use one outer aplly join
and you can delete where clause line